# Low GPU utilisation when running Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, openai-gym

I've been doing Deep Reinforcement Learning using Tensorflow and OpenAI gym. My problem is low GPU utilisation. Googling this issue, I understood that it's wrong to expect much GPU utilisation when training small networks ( eg. for training mnist). But my Neural Network is not so small, I think. The architecture is similar to the given in the original deepmind paper (more or less). The architecture of my network is summarized below

1. Convolution layer 1 (filters=32, kernel_size=8x8, strides=4)
2. Convolution layer 2 (filters=64, kernel_size=8x8, strides=2)
3. Convolution layer 3 (filters=64, kernel_size=8x8, strides=1)
4. Dense layer   (units=512)
5. Output layer (units=9)

I am training on a Tesla P100 16GB gpu. My learning algorithm is Simple DQN. (Again, from the Deepmind paper). Hyper-parameters are all as given in the paper. Still GPU utilisation is well below 10% (as shown by nvidia-smi). What could be the possible issue?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os, sys
import gym
from collections import deque
from time import sleep
import os


os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '1'


def reset_graph(seed=142):
    tf.reset_default_graph()


def preprocess_observation(obs):
    img = obs[34:210:2, ::2] # crop and downsize
    return np.mean(img, axis=2).reshape(88, 80) / 255.0


def combine_observations_multichannel(preprocessed_observations):
    return np.array(preprocessed_observations).transpose([1, 2, 0])


n_observations_per_state = 3
preprocessed_observations = deque([], maxlen=n_observations_per_state)
env = gym.make("Breakout-v0")
obs = env.reset()


input_height = 88
input_width = 80
input_channels = 3
conv_n_maps = [32, 64, 64]
conv_kernel_sizes = [(8,8), (4,4), (3,3)]
conv_strides = [4, 2, 1]
conv_paddings = ["SAME"] * 3 
conv_activation = [tf.nn.relu] * 3
n_hidden_in = 64 * 11 * 10  # conv3 has 64 maps of 10x10 each
n_hidden = 512
hidden_activation = tf.nn.relu
n_outputs = env.action_space.n  # Number of discrete actions are available
initializer = tf.variance_scaling_initializer()


def q_network(X_state, name):
    prev_layer = X_state
    with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:
        for n_maps, kernel_size, strides, padding, activation in zip(
                conv_n_maps, conv_kernel_sizes, conv_strides,
                conv_paddings, conv_activation):
            prev_layer = tf.layers.conv2d(
                prev_layer, filters=n_maps, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                strides=strides, padding=padding, activation=activation,
                kernel_initializer=initializer)
        last_conv_layer_flat = tf.reshape(prev_layer, shape=[-1, n_hidden_in])
        hidden = tf.layers.dense(last_conv_layer_flat, n_hidden,
                                 activation=hidden_activation,
                                 kernel_initializer=initializer)
        outputs = tf.layers.dense(hidden, n_outputs,
                                  kernel_initializer=initializer)
    trainable_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,
                                       scope=scope.name)
    trainable_vars_by_name = {var.name[len(scope.name):]: var
                              for var in trainable_vars}
    return outputs, trainable_vars_by_name


X_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, input_height, input_width,
                                            input_channels])
online_q_values, online_vars = q_network(X_state, name="q_networks/online")
target_q_values, target_vars = q_network(X_state, name="q_networks/target")

copy_ops = [target_var.assign(online_vars[var_name])
            for var_name, target_var in target_vars.items()]
copy_online_to_target = tf.group(*copy_ops)


learning_rate = 0.001
momentum = 0.95

with tf.variable_scope("train"):
    X_action = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
    q_value = tf.reduce_sum(online_q_values * tf.one_hot(X_action, n_outputs),
                            axis=1, keep_dims=True)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean((y - q_value) ** 2) 

    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='global_step')
    optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, momentum, use_nesterov=True)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)


replay_memory_size = 500000
replay_memory = deque([], maxlen=replay_memory_size)

def sample_memories(batch_size):
    indices = np.random.permutation(len(replay_memory))[:batch_size]
    cols = [[], [], [], [], []] # state, action, reward, next_state, continue
    for idx in indices:
        memory = replay_memory[idx]
        for col, value in zip(cols, memory):
            col.append(value)
    cols = [np.array(col) for col in cols]
    return cols[0], cols[1], cols[2].reshape(-1, 1), cols[3], cols[4].reshape(-1, 1)


eps_min = 0.1
eps_max = 1.0
eps_decay_steps = 2000000


def epsilon_greedy(q_values, step):
    epsilon = max(eps_min, eps_max - (eps_max-eps_min) * step/eps_decay_steps)
    if np.random.rand() < epsilon:
        return np.random.randint(n_outputs) # random action
    else:
        return np.argmax(q_values) # optimal action

n_steps = 4000000  # total number of training steps
training_start = 10000  # start training after 10,000 game iterations
training_interval = 4  # run a training step every 4 game iterations
save_steps = 1000  # save the model every 1,000 training steps
copy_steps = 10000  # copy online DQN to target DQN every 10,000 training steps
discount_rate = 0.99
skip_start = 5  # Skip the start of every game (it's just waiting time).
batch_size = 64
iteration = 0  # game iterations
checkpoint_dir = './saved_networks'
checkpoint_path = "./saved_networks/dqn_breakout.cpkt"
summary_path = "./summary/"
done = True # env needs to be reset

# Summary variables
svar_reward = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1], dtype=tf.int32)) # Episode reward
svar_mmq = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), dtype=tf.float32) # Episode Mean-Max-Q
svar_loss = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1], dtype=tf.float64))
all_svars = [svar_reward, svar_mmq, svar_loss]
tf.summary.scalar("Episode Reward", tf.squeeze(svar_reward))
tf.summary.scalar("Episode Mean-Max-Q", tf.squeeze(svar_mmq))
tf.summary.scalar("Episode MSE", tf.squeeze(svar_loss))
# Placeholders
svar_reward_p, svar_mmq_p =  tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [1]), tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1])
svar_loss_p = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [1])
svars_placeholders = [svar_reward_p,  svar_mmq_p, svar_loss_p]

# Assign operation
summary_assign_op = [all_svars[i].assign(svars_placeholders[i]) for i in range(len(svars_placeholders))]
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(summary_path)
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
# For keeping track of no. of episodes played.
episode_step = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1], dtype=tf.int64), trainable=False)
inc_episode_count = episode_step.assign_add([1])


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()


loss_val = np.infty
game_length = 0
total_max_q = 0
mean_max_q = 0.0
ep_reward = 0
ep_loss = 0.

with tf.Session() as sess:
    if os.path.isfile(checkpoint_path + ".index"):
        saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)
        print("<--------------------- Graph restored! -------------------------->")
    else:
        print("<--------- No checkpoints found! Starting over.. ---------------->")
        init.run()
        copy_online_to_target.run()
    while True:
        step = global_step.eval()
        if step >= n_steps:
            break
        iteration += 1
        print("\rIteration {}\tTraining step {}/{} ({:.1f})%\tLoss {:5f}\tMean Max-Q {:5f}   ".format(
            iteration, step, n_steps, step * 100 / n_steps, loss_val, mean_max_q), end="")
        if done: # game over, start again
            obs = env.reset()
            # Clear observations from the past episode
            preprocessed_observations.clear()
            for skip in range(skip_start): # skip the start of each game
                obs, reward, done, info = env.step(0) # Do nothing
                preprocessed_observations.append(preprocess_observation(obs))
            state = combine_observations_multichannel(preprocessed_observations)
        # Online DQN evaluates what to do
        q_values = online_q_values.eval(feed_dict={X_state: [state]})
        action = epsilon_greedy(q_values, step)

        # Online DQN plays
        obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        ep_reward += reward
        preprocessed_observations.append(preprocess_observation(obs))
        next_state = combine_observations_multichannel(preprocessed_observations)

        # Let's memorize what happened
        replay_memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, 1.0 - done))
        state = next_state

        # Compute statistics for tracking progress
        total_max_q += q_values.max()
        game_length += 1
        if done:
            mean_max_q = total_max_q / game_length
            # Write summary -- start
            if iteration >= training_start:
                sess.run(summary_assign_op, feed_dict={
                    svar_reward_p: [ep_reward],
                    svar_mmq_p: [mean_max_q],
                    svar_loss_p: [ep_loss],
                })
                summaries_str = sess.run(summary_op)
                writer.add_summary(summaries_str, sess.run(episode_step))
                sess.run(inc_episode_count)
            # Write summary -- end
            total_max_q = 0.0
            game_length = ep_reward = ep_loss = 0

        if iteration < training_start or iteration % training_interval != 0:
            continue # only train after warmup period and at regular intervals

        # Sample memories and use the target DQN to produce the target Q-Value
        X_state_val, X_action_val, rewards, X_next_state_val, continues = (
            sample_memories(batch_size))
        next_q_values = target_q_values.eval(
            feed_dict={X_state: X_next_state_val})
        max_next_q_values = np.max(next_q_values, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        y_val = rewards + continues * discount_rate * max_next_q_values

        # Train the online DQN
        _, loss_val = sess.run([training_op, loss], feed_dict={
            X_state: X_state_val, X_action: X_action_val, y: y_val})
        ep_loss += loss_val
        # Regularly copy the online DQN to the target DQN
        if step % copy_steps == 0:
            copy_online_to_target.run()

        # And save regularly
        if step % save_steps == 0:
            saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path)
```

Answer (score 3):

Both the original DQN network and the network you use are very small for a Tesla P100 GPU. If you want to utilize more, you can run multiple experiments on the same GPU.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to tell for sure without more details (such as seeing your code, knowing which gym environments you're training on, CPU utilization, hyperparam values, ...). Some possible reasons:

- Low batch size
- The `step()` function of the environment will still be running on your CPU, if that part takes a lot of time your GPU will be sitting idle for a while every iteration
- The same as above counts for all kinds of other code in every iteration of your training loop (such as tracking results, storing stuff in replay buffer, fetching stuff from replay buffer)

---

EDIT after code was added to the question:

After briefly inspecting the code, I suspect the easiest way to increase GPU utilization will be to reduce the `training_interval` parameter's value from `4` to, for example, `1`. Basically, all the tensorflow-based code will be running on GPU (should be at least), and all the other code is going to be on CPU. In iterations where you do not train, this means that only the forwards-pass through the network to compute the Q-values runs on GPU, and all other code is on CPU. In the iterations where you do train, you'll have much more code running on GPU: the additional forwards pass with samples from the replay buffer, and the matching backwards pass for updating the network's parameters. So, if you want to increase GPU utilization, you'll want to do so by increasing how often you run the code that actually runs on GPU.

Apart from that, I think it's also possible to move some of the computations you currently do outside of Tensorflow into Tensorflow (and therefore move them from CPU to GPU). For example, you do the epsilon-greedy action selection outside of Tensorflow, whereas the [OpenAI Baselines DQN implementation](https://github.com/openai/baselines/tree/master/baselines/deepq) does that within Tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are you referring to the OpenAI Gym step(action) method ? How can I ensure it runs on GPU ?  Also, please take a look at my updated question with code.

Comment: @NileshPS yes that's the step() method I was referring to. It's very difficult (probably close to impossible) to make that run on GPU. You probably don't even want that to run on GPU though, it probably doesn't involve the kinds of computations that GPUs are good at (e.g. matrix multiplications). That method is likely much faster on CPU than GPU. I did edit some other tips into my answer though